# reading a series of numbers

Tags: c++

Input:
The input will consist of a series of pairs of integers a and b,separated by a space, one pair of integers per line. you should read the input until EOF.

Output:
For each pair of input integers a and b you should output the sum of a and b in one line,and with one line of output for each line in input.
Sample Input:

```
1 5
7 2
```

Sample Output:

```
6
9
```

My code:

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

int main(){      
    int a=1,b;    
    do
    {
        cin>>a;
        if(a==EOF)
            break;
        cin>>b;
        cout<<a+b;
    }while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

These are my errors:

```
Main.cc: In function 'int main()':
Main.cc:8: error: 'EOF' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: It looks like 3 of us reformatted the post at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way to use streams:

```
int a, b;

if (!(std::cin >> a >> b)) { /* error! */ }

std::cout << a + b << std::endl;
```

If you're in a loop, you can even say:

```
while (std::cin >> a >> b)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`cin>>a;` does not set `a` to anything when it reaches the end of the file, it changes the state of the stream.  You check the end of the file by checking the state of `cin` itself:

```
    cin >> a;
    if (!cin) 
        break;
```